# android SEND key crashes

Tags: android, keyevent

I have a need to check for the enter key to start a search routine. All works except some keyboards seem to have a SEND button instead of the ENTER button.  When this is pressed the code dumps.  I have a small sample below.  Any ideas?

```
tx1.setOnEditorActionListener (new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + event.getKeyCode()); //BLOWS UP HERE
        if  (event.getAction() ==  KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace for your "code dump".

Comment: please take a bit effort in formatting the code you paste. I makes helping a lot easier!

Comment: @CommonsWare:  the code dump is on the line indicated.  Null pointer, but I don't know how to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that event is null in this case.  for detecting the send action on the softkeyboard your onEditorActionListener should actually just do this.

```
onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
    if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND){
        send();
    }
    return false;// so the softkeyboard will still close after pressing 'send'
}
```

Comment: I really do not want to mess with the send key I was just looking for the enter key.  But if the send key closes the keyboard that could be the problem

Comment: This fixed the problem.  I checked for the SEND key and ran the function that did the work.  Then I checked for the event which must have been NULL as you thought.   thanks for the help!

Comment: If you aren't wanting a send key double check your IMEoptions you could change it back to enter, or go etc